# Time dilation paradox

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon, observers

Due to time dilation, a distant observer never sees a black hole but a collapsing star.  Given enough time would he/she receive a large amount of energy from this forever collapsing star?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blueshift

Comment: “*forever collapsing*” is classically correct, but practically grossly exaggerated. The star collapses within the Planck distance to the horizon in a fraction of a second. The Planck distance is the smallest in physics. No further collapse has any physical meaning. The star becomes indistinguishable from a black hole.

Comment: Is there a solution to "forever collapsing" within classical physics?  In accordance with Oppenheimer and Snyder light from the surface of the collapsing star cannot escape if not in an increasingly narrower cone due to deflection so that, apart from the effect of gravity, the star would cut off its link to any distant observer.  Is there any problem with this answer?